# Function inside angular service not seen as a function (again)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, my service is declared as follows:

```
var StateService = angular.module('StateService', [])
.service('HoldState', function ($http, $q) {
```

Inside of that service I have these functions:

```
this.setTypeOfLaw = function (a) { localStorage.setItem('LawType', a) };
    this.setCourthouse = function (a) { localStorage.setItem('Building', a) };
    this.setDepartment = function (a) { localStorage.setItem('Dept', a) };
    this.getTypeOfLaw = function () {
        var LT = localStorage.getItem('LawType');
        return LT;
    };
    this.getCourthouse = function () {
        var BLDG = localStorage.getItem('Building');
        return BLDG;
    };
    this.getDepartment = function () {
        var DEPT = localStorage.getItem('Dept');
        return DEPT;
    };
```

My controller injects my service as follows:

```
JBenchApp.controller('CaseListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'HoldState', 
  function ($scope, $http, HoldState) {
```

It is also injected in the app.js file.

If I add code to the controller that says

```
var a = HoldState.getDepartment();
```

I receive an error that states "getDepartment" is not a function. What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods can be added to services as follows

```
var StateService = angular.module('StateService', [])
.service('HoldState', function ($http, $q) {
 return {
      getDepartment : function() {
      ...
      }
   }
}
```

Then accessed as:

```
HoldState.getDepartment();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This one is the same as the answer below, but this one came first and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Services, Factories and Providers in angular in singletons  and need to return their public api to be available when injected.

```
var StateService = angular.module('StateService', [])
.service('HoldState', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        setTypeOfLaw : function (a) { localStorage.setItem('LawType', a) },
        setCourthouse : function (a) { localStorage.setItem('Building', a) },
        setDepartment : function (a) { localStorage.setItem('Dept', a) },
        getTypeOfLaw : function () {
            var LT = localStorage.getItem('LawType');
            return LT;
        },
        getCourthouse : function () {
            var BLDG = localStorage.getItem('Building');
            return BLDG;
        },
        getDepartment : function () {
            var DEPT = localStorage.getItem('Dept');
            return DEPT;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you could just return the `this` object in your service code:

```
var StateService = angular.module('StateService', [])
  .service('HoldState', function ($http, $q) {
    this.setTypeOfLaw = function (a) { localStorage.setItem('LawType', a) };
    // add all your other functions and code as well
    return this;  // this is the service that will be injected into the controller
  }
```

But without the full service definition, or at least full enough, it's hard to say exactly what you are doing incorrectly.